# How to run old simulators in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode

I have downloaded old simulators, as given in image

[image: Simulator Installed]

Here 6.0 and 6.1 are installed.

As I go To View simulator and devices, it shows as

[image: Devices and Simulator List]

As, I open Deployment Target, it says only one, latest iOS7, as given below
[image]

How can I add Simulator 6.1 and old, so that I can test APP on OLDER VERSIONS of iOS.

I checked the Path

***/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs***

and I found these are already there.

[image]